# How to send input value as request parameter of a link to a servlet?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have a jsp page that loads content from the database according to what the user needs to see (Loading book information). But i also need the user to enter to enter the quantity at the same jsp page.

I used JSTL tags to retrieve information from the database and display it using the following code.

```
 <c:forEach var="book" items="${listBooks.rows}">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${book.bookID}"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${book.bookName}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${book.bookType}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${book.Price}" /></td>
```

This information is set to c:param so i can use it in the servlet.

I have a HTML text for the user to enter the quantity. My question is how can i send this as a parameter to the servlet since the request object is not retrieving the quantity parameter (I'm guessing this is because it's not inside a form that directs to the specific servlet (AddBookServlet).

My code

```
<form>
<td>Quantity:  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" style="height:30px; width: 45px"/>

</td>
 </form>
 <td><a style="color: blue;" class="myButton1"
       href=<c:url value="/AddBookServlet">

       <c:param name="id" value="${book.bookID}"/>
       <c:param name="name" value="${book.bookName}"/>
       <c:param name="type" value="${book.type}"/>
       <c:param name="amount" value="${book.price}"/>

       <c:param name="seat" value="${param.quantity}"  /><%-- not sure if this is the way to do it--%>

</c:url> > &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Add book</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never seen such approach before: why having a form without an action, method and submit button?

If you use it the way it's intended to be used you should be fine.

You can pre-populate the form with values retrieved from the database and leave the quantity input field blank, then retrieve the quantity attribute as you would normally do

```
<c:forEach var="book" items="${listBooks.rows}">
    <form action = "/AddBookServlet" method = "post">

        <td>Book name: <input type="text" name = "bname" value="${book.bookName}"/></td>
        <!-- put the rest of the fields here !-->

        <td>Quantity:  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" style="height:30px; width: 45px"/></td>

        <input type="submit" value="Add Book"/>

    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

Now if you want to prevent the user from editing input fields apart from quantity, which I think is what you were trying to achieve you can add the `readonly` HTML attribute (or set the input type to hidden if for some reason you don't want the field to be displayed to the user)

```
<td>Book name: <input type="text" name = "bname" value="${book.bookName}" readonly="readonly"> </input></td>
```

Then in the doPost method of the `"/AddBookServlet"` you should be able to retrieve each field calling the `request.getParameter("nameOfParameter")`

Comment: Why would be the book's name an input field? Simply print it out and pass it's ID in a hidden field.

Comment: @Peter I agree with you but I was under the impression that he was trying to pass each field to the servlet as parameters, maybe not to retrieve them again from the db

Comment: I guess he will have to, if he wants to continue to work with a book object, but I get the point now. Bonus score for the readonly attribute - disabled field is not getting submitted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating it I think. Forget about `<c:param>` here.

For the `<form>`, you should define `action="YourServletName"` and `method="GET"` or `method="POST"`, then in the servlet's `doGet()` or `doPost()` you can read the parameter like this:

```
String quantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
```

Then of course you'll cast it to some kind of numeric type.